# DevComponents ComboBoxEx

Tags: c#

Utilizo la versión 8.0 de **DotnetBar DevComponents**.

Quisiera saber cómo se puede cambiar el color de fondo de un **ComboBoxEx** por un color personalizado, si utilizo la propiedad *BackColor = MyColor* el color de fondo sigue blanco.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con este código:

```
ComboBoxEx1.UseCustomBackColor = True 'Habilita los colores personalizados.
    ComboBoxEx1.BackColor = Color.DarkRed 'Cambia el color de fondo por rojo oscuro.
    ComboBoxEx1.ForeColor = Color.White 'Cambia el color de la fuente por blanco.
```

Los colores los puedes cambiar a tu gusto, pero es importante que uses siempre la primera.

Esto lo puedes aplicar en el evento "Form1_Load".

Por lo que veo usas C#, pero con eso te puedes dar una idea.